# If $A$, $B$ are two $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices, when the eigenvalues of $A$ are larger than the eigenvalues of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices, so they have $n$ real eigenvalues up to multiplicity. Denote the eigenvalues of $A$ in increasing order, say $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq  \lambda_n$. Similarly, we denote the eigenvalues of $B$ as $\nu_i$.

> Are there any sufficient conditions to guarantee that $\lambda_i \geq \nu_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, e.g. when $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @user1551 It surely implies that $A-B$ has non-negative eigenvalues, but why does it imply my question?

Comment: By Weyl's inequality.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your comment!